# HTML AJAX for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a solution in asp.net c# using the twitter bootstrap framework. on one of the pages I would like to show a modal popup with a asp.net page in it. I am aware that one could use iframe but I am trying to avoid that.

does any one know of a way to implement a ajax modal for remote pages. the remote pages will also have postback and ideally the ajax modal will use the css files from bootstrap.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery `.html` to load the contents: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/q6NqY/).

`$("#my_div_to_insert_content_into").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">');`